# Shredding Nested JSON in snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant

We have scenario to Shred the below JSON (records & array) in a variant column to a relational views and we are able to achieve (shown below - 3 Views).
However if we want to stich/join all three records we don't have any keys to join, do we have any function/ways in snowflake to add keys  dynamically when we shred the view like fk/pk ids.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do this is, create a hash key from names and add it to the other tables. (Borrowed hash key concept from Data Vault)

Your views would look like

```
EMP_REC
EMP_KEY (Hash key of FName + LName using MD5 or similar)
FNAME
LNAME

ADDRESS
EMP_KEY
FLATE
ST

SEMESTER_MARKS
EMP_KEY
MATHS
SCIENCE
```